# Repeat Frame Query Returns Null and the objects inside the frame are not displayed

Tags: oracle11g, oraclereports

I have a repeated frame which has 10 fields inside it.
Whenever the query fetches 0 rows, the repeated frame does not display any field.
I want the frame to display atleast the fields without any values
How to do it in Oracle reports.Any leads would be of much help
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to display **labels**, even though there aren't any values to be displayed.

If that's so, move labels out of the repeating frame, but within its parent *group* frame. For example: if repeating frame's name is R_1, then labels should be part of M_1 which is parent of R_1.

```
-M_1 frame ----------------------------------------

ID         Name         Address ...           --> labels

-R_1 frame ---------------------------------------

ID_field   Name_field   Address_field ...     --> fields within the repeating frame
```

In order to do that:

- set flex off, otherwise you'll "resize" all objects as you'll be moving labels around
- resize repeating frame so that there's enough space above it, but still within the parent group frame
- set confine off, so that you could move labels out (up, actually) of the repeating frame

Once you're done, you'll probably want to set both flex and confine back ON.

Comment: Is that the only way to do that? Because I have similar block this as well? Anyother option to display the labels inside repeat frame when the query r etruns null?

Comment: If there is any, I don't know it.